# Is the relationship between the Department entity and the Instructor entity in Microsoft's Contoso University model wrong?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship, rdbms

[Following this tutorial on Microsoft's documentation site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0)...

[image]

The relationship between the `Instructor` table and `Department` table shows a `0..1` on the `Instructor` and a `*` on the `Department`. If this statement is true:

A department may or may not have an administrator, and an administrator is always an instructor. Therefore the InstructorID property is included as the foreign key to the Instructor entity, and a question mark is added after the int type designation to mark the property as nullable. The navigation property is named Administrator but holds an Instructor entity:

```cs
public int? InstructorID { get; set; }
```

I agree, no problem because the `?` indicates a `Department` may or may not have an `Administrator`.

```cs
public Instructor Administrator { get; set; }
```

....also agree, an `Administrator` must be an `Instructor`.

Why then, in the ER diagram, is the relationship shown as `Instructor` (Administrator) `0..1` and the `Department` shows a `*` (many) symbol?  It seems if the Department has an Sdministrator, then the relationship should be a `0..1` to `1`.

I also do not understand why the relationship between the `Department` entity and the `Instructor` entity is not shown in the ER diagram or the Class definition where there should be a navigation property showing an enumeration property for Departments.

```cs
namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
{
    public class Department
    {
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "money")]
        public decimal Budget { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public int? InstructorID { get; set; }

        public Instructor Administrator { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        
// This property below is not shown in the tutorial, why not?
        public ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The ER diagram is on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and is entitled ["Entity Diagram Showing Relationships"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
Paraphrase or quote from other text with credit. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS Here yes give a diagram to ask about diagramming but give it as text/DDL too.

Comment: This is isn't actually an ER diagram, it's a diagram of a style that is ubiquitously wrongly called an ER diagram. Also in such presentations/methods participations/FKs are ubiquitously wrongly called relationships. But what is the diagramming method & how is it meant to be read, per which you think the diagram is wrong? Identifying, following & referencing it come before asking & posting.

Answer (score 3):

Briefly:

1. A collection-like navigation property of `departments` may be presented, but not in Department class, like you marked in the sample code, but rather - in Instructor class. It cannot be in the department: the Department does not link to (or have, or consists of, etc) many Departments - and existence of such field would mean exactly that. OTOH, on the Instructor side, it would be good: Instructor links to many departments. All right. But it's not strictly necessary to have eveything fully modelled like this. Very often having the relation marked in the code just on one side is totally enough. It depends on how those classes are going to be used. Surely department needs to know who's his admin, but it may be not that really important to ***immediately*** see how many departments a person manages. "Immediately" - because even if the 'collection' is not there, we can still find it out using lookup via Department class.
2. the diagram is correct, it's the way of reading it a bit "unnatural" when you first see it. Try reading it like this, and it will be clear (but probably still not very natural)

[image]

Comment: Well, my mind was thinking Instructors, for the Department entity but my fingers wrote Departments.... :/

Comment: Thank you @quetzalcoatl. Are you saying that an Instructor can work in many departments?

Comment: I just ran the app, and why yes, this is the way it is coded.  I think MS got it wrong.  A department like Engineering is not going to have English majors in it and vice versa.  Or more succinctly, if I am an instructor I am not going to know anything about Engineering if I teach English.

Comment: @BrianDietrich Well.. from one side, these kinds of examples are not meant to be 100% correct in terms of real-world quirks, so yeah, small issues like that may happen without huge problem for educational example. But then, real life often surprises people who want to place such "obvious restrictions" like you suggested. Is it really impossible for a person to run two departments? Say, maths and economy? Philosophy and religion? etc. So, dropping early assumptions, sometimes you can find a person that administers more than 1 dept. But it may be hard to find a dept having more than 1 head...

Comment: anyway, aside from my (probably) broken terminology, I hope you can get what I tried to convey. It might have been a little clearer if they said "person" instead of "instructor". They considered "being an administator" of the department. So certainly one "person" could be an "administrator" of several departments, it sometimes happens IRL. It just depends on the depts, and people, and candidates available... Probably happens rarely, but not impossible. So, dept --> has 0/1 admin (a person/instructor), and a person/instructor is an administrator in 0/* departments, hence the image is correct.

Comment: The hard thing about modelling relations is not assuming too much. We would love to model rules and restrictions and keep things in bonds. But more often than not, later it turns out that real-world cases prove those restrictions wrong. Take for example National ID numbers. In my country, each person has got 1 personal number at birth, then later another 1 as a tax payer id, and few others. Those numbers have "format", "control digits", some digits have meanings like "1:male/2:female". Nice thing to validate. But some people have WRONG numbers. I.e. an 8 on 'sex' digit, totally invalid.

Comment: And that is why you have what is called the bathtub curve in programming.  A group of analysts and stakeholders get together and design what system they need but over time, other stakeholders come in and want something changed, you reprogram, it breaks things and on down the y axis of time until the system loses it's usefulness.

Comment: Well.. often, yes. But it's not impossible to make your system and/or model fluid enough to cope with changes.. as business evolves, and law evolves, systems evolve as well. But surely oh that takes so much exrta effort. That's why you often see nicely modelled relations like here, and IRL you often find the same things kept loose either as meta-data (person has attributes (not data columns!), person has roles (not table relations!), etc) as opposed to hard-wired relations :) anyways, I think I started rambling, sorry. Have fun modelling & coding :)